# How do I upgrade my AWS CloudFormation ECS compose-cli build now that it is deprecated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr

Currently, our AWS CodePipeline uses a `buildspec.yml` which builds, tags, and pushes a Docker container.

Then, it runs the following commands to generate a `cloudformation.yml` file:

```bash
# install Compose CLI, per their instructions
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose-cli/main/scripts/install/install_linux.sh | sh

docker context create ecs $ENVIRONMENT_NAME --from-env
docker context use $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
docker compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.$ENVIRONMENT_NAME.yml --project-name $ECS_CLUSTER_NAME convert > cloudformation.yml
```

As of November 2023, the https://github.com/docker/compose-cli dependency is no longer supported. How can I upgrade the build script to continue functioning after the end of this support?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose-ecs

Comment: That one doesn't even have a release or build

Comment: I think you are stuck exporting the CloudFormation template one last time, and then just using CloudFormation directly from now on, or else rewriting your infrastructure in Terraform or something. There is no other path forward.